# Understanding the definition of a recursive function

Tags: haskell

Hi could anyone explain to me how these pieces of code come about their answers?

```
pip = phi 4 where phi x = if x == 1 then 1 else 1+ phi (x - 1) * phi (x - 1)
```

This returns a result of 26.

```
dpip = phi 5 where phi x = if x == 1 then 1 else 1+ phi (x - 1) * phi (x - 1)
```

And this returns a result of 677.

Also a similar piece of code

```
plip = phi 4 where phi x = 1 + sum [ phi y | y <- [1.. (x-1)]]
```

Returns a result of 8 whereas

```
plips = phi 5 where phi x = 1 + sum [ phi y | y <- [1.. (x-1)]]
```

Returns a result of 16.

I really have no idea how these results are achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break them down

```
pip = phi 4 where phi x = if x == 1 then 1 else 1+ phi (x - 1) * phi (x - 1)
```

can be broken into two lines

```
pip = phi 4

phi x = if x == 1 then 1 else 1+ phi (x - 1) * phi (x - 1)
```

The first line is easy, the second is a recursive definition

```
phi 4 = 1 + phi 3 * phi 3
phi 3 = 1 + phi 2 * phi 2
phi 2 = 1 + phi 1 * phi 1
phi 1 = 1
```

And substituting back up the chain

```
phi 1 = 1
phi 2 = 1 + 1 * 1 = 2
phi 3 = 1 + 2 * 2 = 5
phi 4 = 1 + 5 * 5 = 26
```

Your next problem just goes one step further up the chain

```
phi 5 = 1 + phi 4 * phi 4
      = 1 + 26 * 26
      = 677
```

A similar analysis works for the second piece of code.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I actually used your well laid out answer and Impredicative's explanation of how the computer descends the stack first to find a base case and then works its way back up from there taking the result from the previous "phi" to compute the next result. With both of these insights I was able to work out how the second piece of code works as well.

Answer (score 3):

I will explain the 1st and 3rd and from there you should be able to figure out the rest.

In the first snippet we're calling

```
phi 4
1 + phi 3 * phi 3
1 + (1 + phi 2) * (1 + phi 2)
1 + (1 + (1 + 1) * (1 + 1)) * (1 + (1 + 1) * (1 + 1))
1 + 5 * 5
26
```

This follows from simply expanding and simplifying.

For the 3rd,

```
 phi 4
 1 + sum [phi 1, phi 2, phi 3]
 1 + sum [1, phi 2, phi 3]
 1 + sum [1, 2, phi 3]
 1 + sum [1, 2, 4]
 1 + 7
 8
```

Answer (score 2):

So, in the `pip` example, we have the following definition:

```
phi x = if x == 1 then 1 else 1+ phi (x - 1) * phi (x - 1)
```

Let's evaluate this for some numbers:

1. `phi 1` - well, first we check that `x == 1`, which it is, so we return 1. Hence `phi 1 == 1`.
2. `phi 2` - Here, we go down the `else` branch. `x-1` is now `1`, and we know the value of `phi 1`, so we get that `phi 2 == 1+1*1 == 2`.
3. Likewise for `phi 3`, we get that `phi 3 = 1+2*2 == 5`
4. And hence for `phi 4`, `1+5*5 == 26`.

The same analysis runs for the other code. In general, the principle is that the computer descends the stack until it reaches a base case, and then ascends the stack using that base case to compute higher answers.

[Here's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion) a question on programmers.stackexchange.com that explains the concept of recursion, which seems to be the concept you're struggling with here.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you read it from the end:

`phi x = if x == 1 then 1 else 1+ phi (x - 1) * phi (x - 1)`

This defines a recursive function `phi`; the results are

> phi(1) -> 1
>
> phi(2) -> 1 + phi(2-1)*phi(2-1) = 1 + phi(1)*phi(1) = 1 + 1 = 2
>
> phi(3) -> 1 + phi(3-1)*phi(3-1) = 1 + phi(2)*phi(2) = 1 + 4 = 5
>
> phi(4) -> 1 + 5*5 = 26
>
> phi(5) -> 1 + 26*26 = 677

The definition for phi inside the plip function uses a for comprehension:

`phi x = 1 + sum [ phi y | y <- [1.. (x-1)]]`

This sums the values for phi(y) for all y's between 1 and x-1.